# I am trying to extract pos tags by sentence and word annotations, where some sentences give sentence annotation error

Tags: r

I have a problem with sentence annotation

I tried breaking a review to sentences and then annotate each sentence 
for pos tags. But it didn't work.

```r
review=as.String(servqual$Review_Text[186])
review_split=str_split(review,"[:punct:]")

for (l in 1:(lengths(review_split)-1)) 
{

  string1=as.String(review_split[[1]][l])
  sent_token_annotator=Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
  word_token_annotator=Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
  annotate_word=annotate(string1,list(sent_token_annotator,word_token_annotator))
  pos_tag_annotator=Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
  annotate_pos=annotate(string1,pos_tag_annotator,annotate_word)
  subset_word=subset(annotate_pos,type=="word")
  tags_word=sapply(subset_word$features,'[[',"POS")

  s_word_tag=as.String(sprintf("%s%s%s",string1[subset_word],"/",tags_word))
  review_split[[1]][l]=str_replace_all(s_word_tag,"\n"," ")

}
```

> Error in e(s, a) : no sentence token annotations found.
>   traceback()
>   6: stop("no sentence token annotations found")
>   5: e(s, a)
>   4: paste(y$id, y$type, y$start, y$end, sep = "\r")
>   3: merge.Annotation(a, e(s, a))
>   2: merge(a, e(s, a))
>   1: annotate(string1, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))

I expect the output as pos tags with each word of all sentences.

Comment: Please post a sample of your data with `dput(servqual)` so that we are better able to help you. Also, what libraries have you loaded prior to running this code?

Comment: Data is just a review(string).

Comment: Libraries used are stringr,stringi and openNLP